# How is a dragonlength a reliable measure of length on Pern?

Tags: pern

In the post-dragon society of Pern, a common measurement of length is called "a dragonlength", which seems to be somewhere 20 meters or 50-60 feet. However, the size of dragons varies greatly by color, with the largest varieties (bronze/gold) being nearly twice the size of the smallest (green).

Also, the overall size of dragons was designed to increase with each generation. Over the course of 2500 years, the average dragon size increased by almost 400% from the original genetically-designed creations. Despite this, however, the terms "dragonlength" and "length" (apparently a smaller measurement?) are universally used by the people of Pern, even those outside of Weyr culture such as holders and craftsmen.

**Given the variety of sizes, both overall and within each color bracket, how is "a dragonlength" a reliable measure of length on Pern?**

Comment: When I used to work in UK coal mines a common measurement  was a 'pan-length'. This was an estimate of five feet. I'm not sure why (It may have had something to do with sections of an Armoured Flexible Conveyor but I never measured one of those sections to confirm)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A "dragon length" isn't a dependable measure.

It is a rough and ready measure that refers to a common (or at least well known) object to convey approximate, relatively large lengths.

I don't recall any discussion of it in the books, and I really don't see that there's any need for it to be addressed explicitly.  It is a thing people do  - you describe one thing by reference to another.  If I tell you there was a gap in a hedge as wide as a car, you have an immediate, approximate idea, of how wide it is - though cars can vary in actual width.

Many measurements in history started as such rough and ready measurements, and were later standardized.

Take the "mile."  It was originally one thousand paces - the step size of the person walking.  "Mile" being a corruption of "mille" (thousand) from the original phrase "mille passus."  These days, it is a standard length of 5280 feet.  It is defined as 1609.344 m, which then ties back (through the definition of the meter) to a particular number of wavelengths of a particular color of light emitted by a particular gas.

So, a dragon length may be still a rough and ready unit for approximate measure, or a standardized unit with a specific length.  Or, it may be both at the same time.  A specific standard length that is often measured "in the wild" by referring to a handily available dragon - much the same as a person today might measure the approximate length of a garden path by counting paces and calling them meters.

And, finally, it just doesn't matter.

The important part is that it conveys a size to you (the reader) in a way that also makes sense for the people in the story and that does so in a way that the reader will accept as believable.

At no point in the Pern stories is a precise measurement in dragon lengths made such that the imprecision would be a problem.   The sea ships navigate by other means, seed needed to plant a field is estimated by approximate size (in dragon lengths) and experience (and isn't precise either.)

So, it just doesn't matter.

Comment: Example: a fathom is defined as six feet, originally the rough distance between outstretched fingertips. When I worked on a fishing boat and a line had to be so many fathoms long, it was quickly measured simply by how many full arm-lengths were needed. If a line was counted out to ten fathoms, it almost certainly wasn't exactly 60 feet, but it was close enough.